# Does CRAN have an empty package

Tags: r, cran

I am currently setting up a a locally hosted CRAN mirror of "approved" packages (using `miniCran`). To satisfy the parameters of some of miniCRAN's functions, I've taken to including a "dummy" package in my lists.

I was wondering if there is an existing library that is "empty" and does nothing. I'm currently including `uuid`, but was hoping there was something specifically designed for that.